# Java, Sets particular HashSet TreeSet

Tags: java, hash, tree, set

Trying to save words from a .txt-file in a set. Never used sets before.

```
Set<Word> set = new HashSet<Word>();
```

When saving in the hashset I get size to 241.
If I change the above to

```
Set<Word> set = new TreeSet<Word>();
```

and nothing else in the code, I get size to 231. Is there some kind of natural cause of this in the different sets?

Comment: Can we see your `Word` class? Does it override `hashCode` and `equals` methods?

Comment: Yeah, it was the equals-method, thx!

Answer (score 6):

You probably aren't making `Comparable.compareTo` consistent with `Object.equals/hashCode`. That or `hashCode` is not consistent with `equals`. Possibly not actually overridden `hashCode` - use `@Override` to make sure.

Comment: Yeah, it was my implementation of equals-method, thx alot! =)